# How to dynamically choose what concrete class to use in dependency injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, factory-pattern, strategy-pattern

I usually write something like this for my `DI`:

```
var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddSingleton<ISomething, Something>()
            .AddSingleton<IOutputMaker, XMLOutputMaker>()
            .AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Program.configuration)
            .BuildServiceProvider();
```

But now let's say I read from a `config file` what `type` of output I should generate. Notice that above I have this line:

```
.AddSingleton<IOutputMaker, XMLOutputMaker>()
```

But I want to be more flexible and say for example if config file says `XML` then that, if config file says `XLSX` then maybe this:

```
.AddSingleton<IOutputMaker, ExcelOutputMaker>()
```

How can I do that to be more flexible?

I don't know how. Maybe I can call that `BuildServiceProvider` multiple times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register the concrete implementations, and then register a factory that consults something from the configuration (I've used [options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-7.0), but you could also just resolve `IConfiguration`) to determine which one to return.

```cs
services.AddOptions<SomeOptions>().BindConfiguration("something");
services.AddSingleton<SomethingImplementationOne>();
services.AddSingleton<SomethingImplementationTwo>();
services
    .AddSingleton<ISomething>(sp => {
        var opts = sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<SomeOptions>>();
        switch (opts.DefaultService)
        {
            case "One":
                return sp.GetRequiredService<SomethingImplementationOne>();
            default:
                return sp.GetRequiredService<SomethingImplementationTwo>();
        }
    });
```

For completeness, my `SomeOptions` class looks like this:

```cs
public class SomeOptions
{
    public string DefaultService { get; set; }
}
```

And my JSON for my configuration looks like this:

```cs
{
    "something": {
        "defaultService": "One"
    }
}
```